# Show kernel routing exception entries (FIB)

Tags: linux-kernel, routing

Linux 3.6 removed the ipv4 routing cache ([commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=89aef8921bfbac22f00e04f8450f6e447db13e42)).
[Changelog](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1207.3/00039.html) says:

> Remove the ipv4 routing cache. Now lookups go directly into the FIB
>   trie and use prebuilt routes cached there.

According to this [question](https://superuser.com/a/503440/366260), the routing cache entries are now stored in a *"routing exception" structure which is a part of the routing entry.*

On my 3.16 (Debian Jessie) standard distribution kernel, I can't see any exceptions and `ip route show cache` doesn't return anything.
The routing table only has a default route:

> ~#ip route show
>   default via 10.11.2.30 dev eth0
>   10.11.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.11.1.76

Q1: How can I list all of these routing exceptions that are known to the kernel?
Q2: How can I selectively remove such an exception?
Q3: Why does the kernel not select the correct default gateway when trying to ping a certain host:

> ping 10.30.104.23
>   PING 10.30.104.23 (10.30.104.23) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   From 10.11.1.11 icmp_seq=1 Destination Protocol Unreachable

Addition for Q3: I suspect that this (now obsolete) route was probably stored (somewhere) because of a ICMP redirect. But if `ip route show cache` does not list routing exceptions and the default route says otherwise - where is this bit of information stored?

Answer (score 3):

OK, after much digging I think I have the answers:

A1: Since 3.6 it's no longer possible to list the entire routing cache. You can see the routing cache for specific IPs using `ip route get to A.B.C.D` but can't list all of them.

A2: `ip route flush cache to A.B.C.D` removes a single entry from the route cache.

A3: Argh, could have known that: Because it first consults the routing cache a.k.a. FIB (forwarding information base) and *after* that it looks at the routing table.
See [this PDF](http://www.net.in.tum.de/fileadmin/TUM/NET/NET-2015-09-1/NET-2015-09-1_07.pdf) for a detailed diagram.

Answer (score 0):

lol necro.  I'm posting because I'm running into a routing problem with the FIB interfering with a new entry in the routing table.  It may not be possible to list ***all*** the routes... but you can do a decent lookup with:
[image: ip route get command]

which will show you if there's an FIB route in play.  Additionally, you can also use:
[image: ip route match command]

For the life of me, I can't find a way to display the whole FIB or manipulate it in any way.  I'm sure it will go away if I bounce the interface, but that's a little bit of a pain and may not match all uses cases.